# HighCharts Pattern Fill striped

Tags: javascript, css, highcharts

I'm working with highcharts and have come across an issue. I have a column chart bar graph. I have been fiddling with the colors, and even looked into the high charts pattern fill information mentioned here http://www.highcharts.com/plugin-registry/single/9/Pattern-Fill , but have not been able to achieve what I am looking for. I am trying to make the color of a single bar a striped black and white color. A color like this would do http://thumb1.shutterstock.com/display_pic_with_logo/924836/169423604/stock-photo-seamless-black-white-diagonal-stripe-169423604.jpg

but the bars should be a bit thicker, and they should be tilted the same way. I would like this color to affect just one bar, and not the rest. Is there a way to do this? Both in regards to actually making a pattern fill of this kind as well as making it affect just one bar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if I understood correctly you need change picture on columns with diagonal stripe

this js fiddle demo from official page but I change column settings:

```
 color: {
            pattern: 'http://images2.layoutsparks.com/1/192908/black-white-diagonal-stripes.jpg',
            width: 24,
            height: 24,
  ****
}
```

what this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ls9qbzfv/)